# CSS or jQuery/JavaScript Oval/Rounded Square Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, css, html, progress-bar

I've searched for quite some time regarding an example but can anyone suggest any steps or the best way to implement the following progress bar [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihYxL.png)?

It is essentially a square path with rounded off edges moving in an anti clockwise direction from where the red area is (progress bar is red). I have seen some radial CSS/jQuery examples but they are similar but not fit for purpose regarding shape.  The centre space will have a percentage area.

Any advice on where to start with this would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Comment: hope this may help you a bit 

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: Thanks for the help Tushar, it's similar to what I needed but I managed to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I can use HTML Canvas to achieve this, I just need to animate it.